# what is the use of server conn in websphere MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

1. What is the use of a server conn in Websphere MQ and why do we go for it.
2. What is the difference between client conn and server conn.

Answer (score 2):

In some respects these are two opposite things, but they need to match to make a client connection to a queue manager. Its quite a generic topic but fortunately there is lots of useful documentation about this in google / IBM knowledgebase e.g. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016480_.htm

As a queue manager, if you are going to let clients connect into you, you need to be able to provide some configuration details (heartbeat intervals, max message sizes, user exits) - these are configured on a SVRCONN channel

As an application, if you want to connect into a queue manager via the client bindings (usually to go to another machine), you need some information about the configuration to use and these are configured on a CLNTCONN channel.

The application 'provides' a CLNTCONN channel, and once the connection is made, an equivalent SVRCONN channel is looked up, and the configuration values are negotiated and the connection made.

An application can 'provide' a CLNTCONN channel at least 3 common ways...
- As part of an MQSERVER environment variable
- Via a client channel table (MQCHLLIB/MQCHLTAB environment variables)
- During an MQCONNX call it can provide the channel details

More details here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q027440_.htm